# How to add a new line in the txt field in fpdf cell

Tags: python, fpdf

I'm trying to use fpdf to create a pdf file in python, but I have trouble in the "txt" filed in cell function, because I would like some new lines in the text.
Here is what I do, but this doesn't work.

```
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_xy(0, 0)
pdf.set_font('arial', 'B', 13.0)
text = 'Engagement Summary:' + "\n" + 'opened by: ' + str(shareURL.contact)
pdf.cell(ln=0, h=5.0, align='L', w=0, txt=text, border=0)
pdfName = request.user.username + ".pdf"
pdf.output(pdfName, 'F')
```

ALso, "\n" doesn't work in the email I would like to send.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
pdf.multi_cell(0, 5, 'text' + '\n' +'test asdfaf')
```

Comment: Is there any difference between your code and the other answers presented?

Comment: i tried the other answers without success. so try it and you will know

Answer (score 2):

I'm not as familiar with the python version as I am with the PHP version, but assuming the library works the same, the issues is that cell does not allow for new lines within it. A cell is a essentially just a predefined rectangle with hard stops on the height and width entered.

What you'll need to use instead to add the new lines is: multi_cell multi cell will hard stop at the defined width, but the height will be dynamic based on content. Then you hard part becomes keeping track of positioning for other blocks.

[Phython FPDF Multi Cell](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/multi_cell/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
pdf.cell(ln=1, h=5.0, align='L', w=0, txt=text, border=0)
```

ln should be 1 instead of 0 if you want a line break

Answer (score -2):

you can use pdf.multi_cell(ln=0, h=5.0, align='L', w=0, txt=text, border=0) method instead of pdf.cell(ln=0, h=5.0, align='L', w=0, txt=text, border=0)